# Django: api call view: on redirect, the request method does not change to GET

Tags: django, redirect

I have  `viewA()` and `viewB()`

I am sending a POST request to `viewB()` using curl, like:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewB' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"item" : "new"
}'
```

Inside `viewB()`, I have a `redirect(..to viewA)`.

After redirected to `viewA()`, when I debug inside `viewA()` I see that the `request.method` is `POST` instead of `GET`.

Why `redirect()` does not change `request.method` to `GET`?